# error FOR3309: undefined label 124

Tags: fortran

I wrote this but when I try to build  *.exe say:

```
    Compiling Fortran...
C:\Users\LORD\Desktop\TText1.f90
C:\Users\LORD\Desktop\TText1.f90(197): error FOR3309: undefined label 124
Error executing fl32.exe.
```

This is the source code of the project:

```
      program one

real::x(6),f(6),deltaf1(6),deltaf2(6),deltaf3(6),deltaf4(6),deltaf5(6)

real::gradf1(6),gradf2(6),gradf3(6),gradf4(6),gradf5(6)

real::h,x1,x2,s1,s2,p1,p2,Y1,Y2

real::Z,T,a,b,c,d

open(unit=16,file="E:\N\xi.txt")

open(unit=148,file="E:\N\fi.txt")

  gradf1(:)=0.0
  gradf2(:)=0.0
  gradf3(:)=0.0
  gradf4(:)=0.0
  gradf5(:)=0.0

  deltaf1(:)=0.0
  deltaf2(:)=0.0
  deltaf3(:)=0.0
  deltaf4(:)=0.0
  deltaf5(:)=0.0


do i=0,5

read(16,*)x(i)

read(148,*)f(i)

write(*,12)x(i),f(i)

12 format(2F12.4)

end do

do i=0,4

 deltaf1(i)=f(i+1)-f(i)


 end do

  do i=0,3

  deltaf2(i)=deltaf1(i+1)-deltaf1(i)

    end do

    do i=0,2

      deltaf3(i)=deltaf2(i+1)-deltaf2(i)


     end do

     do i=0,1

        deltaf4(i)=deltaf3(i+1)-deltaf3(i)

        write(*,*)deltaf4(i)


        end do

          deltaf5(5)=deltaf4(1)-deltaf4(0)

          write(*,*)deltaf5(5)

          do i=1,5

          gradf1(i)=f(i)-f(i-1)


          write(*,55)gradf1(i)

          55 format(F12.4)

            end do

    do i=2,5

    gradf2(i)=gradf1(i)-gradf1(i-1)

    write(*,65)gradf2(i)

    65 format(F12.4)

    end do

    do i=3,5

    gradf3(i)=gradf2(i)-gradf2(i-1)

    end do


    do i=4,5

    gradf4(i)=gradf3(i)-gradf3(i-1)

    write(*,124)gradf4(i)

    end do


    gradf5(5)=gradf4(5)-gradf4(4)

    write(*,155)gradf5(5)

    155 format(F12.4)


            h=x(1)-x(0)

           x1=0.5

          s1=(x1-x(0))/h





            write(*,33)s1

            33 format(F12.4)

!p(x)=fi(0)+s*deltafi1(0)+(1/2)*s*(s-1)*deltafi2(0)+(1/6)*s*(s-1)*(s-2)*deltafi3(0)+(1/24)*s*(s-1)*(s-2)*(s-3)*deltafi4(0)+(1/120)*s*(s-1)*(s-2)*(s-3)*(s-4)*deltafi5(0)   

p1=f(0)+s1*deltaf1(0)+(1/2)*s1*(s1-1)*deltaf2(0)+(1/6)*s1*(s1-1)*(s1-2)*deltaf3(0)+(1/24)*s1*(s1-1)*(s1-2)*(s1-3)*deltaf4(0)+(1/120)*s1*(s1-1)*(s1-2)*(s1-3)*(s1-4)*deltaf5(0)


    write(*,*)" vaghti x1=0.5 chand jomleie pishro barabar ast ba=",p1

    x2=0.45

    s2=(x2-x(0))/h

    p2=f(0)+s2*deltaf1(0)+(1/2)*s2*(s2-1)*deltaf2(0)+(1/6)*s2*(s2-1)*(s2-2)*deltaf3(0)+(1/24)*s2*(s2-1)*(s2-2)*(s2-3)*deltaf4(0)+(1/120)*s2*(s2-1)*(s2-2)*(s2-3)*(s2-4)*deltaf5(0)

write(*,*)"vaghti x2=0.45 chand jomleie pishro barabar ast ba=",p2

    !Y(x)=fi(5)+s*gradfi1(5)+(1/2)*s*(s+1)*gradfi2(5)+(1/6)*s*(s+1)*(s+2)*gradfi3(5)+(1/24)*s*(s+1)*(s+2)*(s+3)*gradfi4(5)+(1/120)*s*(s+1)*(s+2)*(s+3)*(s+4)*gradfi5(5)



    Y1=f(5)+s1*gradf1(5)+(1/2)*s1*(s1+1)*gradf2(5)+(1/6)*s1*(s1+1)*(s1+2)*gradf3(5)+(1/24)*s1*(s1+1)*(s1+2)*(s1+3)*gradf4(5)+(1/120)*s1*(s1+1)*(s1+2)*(s1+3)*(s1+4)*gradf5(5)

    write(*,*)"vaghti x1=0.5 chand jomleie pishro barabar ast ba=",Y1

    Y2=f(5)+s2*gradf1(5)+(1/2)*s2*(s2+1)*gradf2(5)+(1/6)*s2*(s2+1)*(s2+2)*gradf3(5)+(1/24)*s2*(s2+1)*(s2+2)*(s2+3)*gradf4(5)+(1/120)*s2*(s2+1)*(s2+2)*(s2+3)*(s2+4)*gradf5(5)

     write(*,*)"vaghti x2=0.45 chand jomleie pasro barabar ast ba=",Y2

     T=abs(p1-Y1)

    Z=abs(p2-Y2)

    write(*,*)"tafazole chand jomleie pishro va pasro baraye x1=0.5 barabar ast ba=",T

    write(*,*)"tafazole chand jomleie pishro va pasro baraye x2=0.45 barabar ast ba=",Z

    ! tabe W ra be in shekl benvis=exp(2*x)

    !W=exp(2*x)

    W1=exp(2*x1)

    W2=exp(2*x2)


    a=abs(p1-W1)

    b=abs(p2-W2)

    c=abs(Y1-W1)

    d=abs(Y2-W2)


    write(*,*)"tafazole chand jomleie pishro va tabe W mord nazar dr noghte x1=0.5 mishavad=",a


    write(*,*)"tafazole chand jomleie pishro va tabe W mord nazar dr noghte x2=0.45 mishavad=",b


    write(*,*)"tafazole chand jomleie pasro va tabe W mord nazar dr  noghte x1=0.5 mishavad=",c


    write(*,*)"tafazole chand jomleie pasro va tabe W mord nazar dr noghte x2=0.45 mishavad=",d

 stop
end program one
```

Comment: Your code is very difficult to read. If your university also examines your coding style be sure to format your code in some better way. For example, your indentation is very inconsistent and does not reveal the structure of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I could say that the problem is that you're using Microsoft Fortran PowerStation, that was discontinued in 1997, but...

You have the line:

```
write(*,124)gradf4(i)
```

That 124 is supposed to be the label of a format, but you have no format labeled 124. You do have a format labeled 12 - maybe that's what is wanted.

Here's what a modern compiler might tell you:

```
t.f90(105): error #6052: This label has not been defined as a FORMAT label.   [124]
    write(*,124)gradf4(i)
------------^
```

Comment: Now what i must do ?

Comment: The simplest is to replace 124 in this statement with 155, since that's the label of a suitable format you already have. It is not good practice to repeat the same format with different labels, and in fact labeled formats are not considered current best practice. Instead, one uses literal formats such as '(F12.4)', but for more complex formats or those that are referenced a lot, labeled formats are ok.

Comment: thanks for your guidance.i replaced and the program made.but when I start *.exe , for second the white screen show and hide.

Comment: thanks for your guidance.i replaced and the program made.but when I start *.exe the white screen show just a second and hide. that mean the program have problem. who know where is problem?

Comment: I suggest that you find someone familiar with the PowerStation environment you're using. StackOverflow is not the place to learn basic tool usage, especially one that has been off the market for 20 years.